# JSON to JSON conversion

Tags: json

I have a 3rd party service which returns me the following response:
JSON 1

```
{"Bag":{"Type":{"$":"LIST"},"Source":{"$":"ABC"},"Id":{"$":"151559458"},"Name":{"$":"Bag list"},"Source":{"$":"ABC"},"CustomerId":{"$":"abc@gmail.com"},"DateTime":{"$":"2014-07-17T12:36:01Z"}}}
```

But I have to format this JSON into the following format:
JSON2

```
{"Bag":{"Type":"LIST","Source":"ABC","Id":"151559458","Name":"Bag list","Source":"ABC","CustomerId":"abc@gmail.com","DateTime":"2014-07-17T12:36:01Z"}}
```

And Vice versa like from client I get JSON2 and I have to send this response to service in JSON1 format.

Answer (score 0):

1. Given the input in the first JSON schema, transform it to a language specific data structure. You can typically find a library to do this.
2. Transform your language specific data structure, using the idioms of whichever language you are using, to the equivalent of the second JSON schema.
3. Transform the language specific data structure to JSON text. You can typically find a library to do this.

Comment: Can you please suggest any library. Coz I didn't find one.

Comment: @gaurav001 - I could probably suggest 50 libraries. You'll need to tell me what language/platform you are working on.

Comment: @ChaosPandion can you suggest library or tool or metalanguage for json to json transformation in JS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jq tool http://stedolan.github.io/jq

Then the conversion is console one-liner:

```
$ jq '{Bag: .Bag | with_entries({key, value: .value."$"})}' file.json
```

And the result is

```
{
  "Bag": {
    "Type": "LIST",
    "Source": "ABC",
    "Name": "Bag\nlist",
    "Id": "151559458",
    "DateTime": "2014-07-17T12:36:01Z",
    "CustomerId": "abc@gmail.com"
  }
}
```